# how to get opening and closing stock in this example using SQL queries in

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
itemid  entrydate       opeingstock stockin  stockout       closingstock
DB07    02-10-14 23:05   94000        0        900            93100
DB07    03-10-14 23:05   93100      1000        0             94100
DB07    03-10-14 23:06   94100        0        500            93600
DB07   14-10-14 23:52    97600        0       1500            96100
```

Comment: What have you tried?
what do you want the final results to look like? you need to be more specific

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
      TABLE1.openingstock, 
      (TABLE1.openingstock + TABLE2.stockin - TABLE2. stockout) 'closingstock'
from 
     TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2
     ON TABLE1.itemid = TABLE2.itemid
```

returns to you the 2 columns...

Please, add more information, like examples, if this is not what you want.

Comment: table1(itemid,openingstock),table2(itemid.entrydate,stockin,stockout)

Comment: @vijay i edit my answer with your new information, is ok now?